# How to redirect to success page by "save action" from WFFM?

Tags: wffm, sitecore-client

I created a WFFM in my sitecore instance and then set save action "Create User". The scenario is that a layout page will be displayed if the action succeeds.

I did like this:
[image]

When I run the form by mode "preview", after the submission, this error "**Most likely causes:
The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) may have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable. Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.
**" has been launched. I can not detect something wrong I did manually configure.

[image]

P/S: sorry to post only the photos, because I only want to tell you all of my steps I did

Comment: you have to redirect to a page not to a layout.

Comment: Yes, that's the problem. But I do not know how to fix it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is: you redirect to a Layout not to a Page after submit.

On "Success Page" field you need to have a page item.

Please have a look on next [link](https://doc.sitecore.net/web_forms_for_marketers/working_with_actions_and_validations/the_submit_button/add_a_success_submit_action_to_a_form)

Comment: It works, tks. But Is it possible to create a new page by duplicating the "Home" page ? I did by that way.

Answer (score 1):

By looking at the screenshot you are trying to redirect to a layout item, which generally do not have Presentation details.
Please click on on the "Insert Link" to pick an internal page or "Insert External Link" to redirect to a page outside your website.
If you want the form to redirect to the layout you are trying to pick, then create an item under Content and assign that layout to it using Presentation-> Details.